# In JavaScript, is chained assignment okay?

Tags: javascript, object, variable-assignment

Am not new to JS or its syntax, but sometimes, the semantics of the language has me stumped at times. At work today, a colleague mentioned this:

```
var a = b = [];
```

is not the same as

```
var a = [], b = [];
```

or

```
var a = []; var b = [];
```

since the first version actually assigns the reference to an empty array to a and b. I couldn't quite accept this as true, but I'm not sure. What do you all think?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758576/multiple-left-hand-assignment-with-javascript/1758912#1758912

Comment: Thank you, Crescent Fresh - I didn't quite see that question because I was looking for "chained assignment".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple left-hand assignment with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758576/multiple-left-hand-assignment-with-javascript)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Yes, they're not the same. `var a = b = []` is equivalent to

```
var a;
b = [];
a = b;
```

Not only do both `a` and `b` get assigned the same value (a reference to the same empty array), `b` is not declared at all. In [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) in ECMAScript 5 and later, this will throw a `ReferenceError`; otherwise, unless there is already a variable `b` in scope, `b` is silently created as a property of the global object and acts similarly to a global variable, wherever the code is, even inside a function. Which is not good.

You can see this quite easily:

```
(function() {
    var a = b = [];
})();

console.log(b); // Shows []
```

Comment: I didn't see immediately about b being a global variable, thanks!

Comment: +1 Another reason to avoid an assignment to an unresolvable reference is that on ES5, under strict mode, a `ReferenceError` will be thrown.

Answer (score 12):

Your colleague is right:

```js
var a = b = [];
a.push('something');
console.log(b); // outputs ["something"]
```

but:

```js
var a = [],
  b = [];
a.push('something');
console.log(b); // outputs []
```

Answer (score 3):

Your colleague is right. The first statement creates a new, empty array. Then, a reference to this array is assigned to b. Then, the same reference (which is the result of the assignment expression) is assigned to a. So a and b refer to the same array.

In all other cases, you create two individual arrays.

By the way: This behavior is quite common and is the same in all C based programming languages. So this is not JavaScript specific.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Tobias, and also for pointing out the commonality in all C-based languages.

Comment: This can be tested with arrays in JS: `["dog"] === ["dog"];` returns false, but `var a = b = ["dog"]; a === b;` returns true.

Answer (score 3):

With the first example `b` is a reference to `a`, and `b` becomes a global variable, accessible from anywhere (and it replaces any `b` variable that may already exist in the global scope).

Answer (score 3):

To complement the already provided answers. ref assignments are different from value assignments

```
var x = y = 3; // by value
y++; // 4
x; // 3

var a = b = []; // by ref
b.push(1); // [1];
a; // [1]
a = [];
a.push(2); // [2];
b; // [1]
```

Now that we've addressed 2 two, your question also makes reference to linting, which is the practice of "pretty code" (not functional). In fact, [JSHint has deprecated all their "pretty code rules"](http://jshint.com/docs/options/)

That been said, I usually use the following style.-

```
var a, b, c, // first row all unassigned
    x = 1, // 1 row per assigned
    y = 2,
    list = [
       'additional',
       'indentation'
    ],
    obj = {
       A: 'A',
       B: 'B'
    };
var z = y +2; // created a new `var` cluster since it uses a var from the previous
```

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this, you need to split the `var` declaration from the chained assignment (see: 
http://davidshariff.com/blog/chaining-variable-assignments-in-javascript-words-of-caution/ ).

E.g.

```
var one = 1, two = 2;

one = two = 3; /* Now both equal 3 */
```

But if you do as you described (`var one = two = 3;` in this example) `two` leaks into the global space, while `one` is declared in the local scope.

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is if it's ok or not, it's ok except in strict mode. Modules are in strict mode by default, so it's not allowed.

```
<script>
  const a=b=1 // allowed
<script>
```

```
<script>
  "user strict"
  const a=b=1 // error
<script>
```

```
<script type="module">
  const a=b=1 // error
<script>
```