# Weird bug or something in jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

All of my elements which init by my jquery plugin sharing the same local variable when it running. I did a test and found out because this line:

```
var tmp1 = tmp2 = weird_local_var = 0;
```

If I write like below, it does not happens

```
var normal_local_var = 0;
```

It is not because tmp1 & tmp2, just dummy var for testing. You can see the test via http://jsfiddle.net/7SeRD/. What happen?

Comment: this is exactly why I recommend against any assignments in a `var` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just change your init line to:

```
var tmp1=0, tmp2=0, weird_local_var=0, normal_local_var=0;

// or
var tmp1=0; 
var tmp2=0;
var weird_local_var=0;
var normal_local_var=0;
```

**EDIT:** See this answer too: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3387339/420001).

From it:

```
var a = b = [] is equivalent to

var a;
b = [];
a = b;
```

What you're doing is *chaining* **assignments**.

You're essentially assigning a reference to weird_local_var (whose value is 0) to tmp2, then assigning a reference to that reference (ie tmp1 -> tmp2) to tmp1.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating v2 and weird_local_var as globals by not using the "var" keyword when you declare them.

try the same thing creating the variables beforehand and it will work as expected:
http://jsfiddle.net/MaxPRafferty/2MKgH/

```
        var v2;
        var weird_local_var;
        var v1 = v2 = weird_local_var = 0;
```