# Are parentheses required in an arrow function definition with default argument values

Tags: javascript

```
var prev = a = new Date() => a; // Error

var prev = (a = new Date()) => a; // Good
```

In the arrow functions, when it is only a parameter, I can omit the parentheses, however when I do this, I must add them.

Is it an error in the architecture of language, or is it the structure of the language itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parenthesis **are** required around your arrow function when using a default value.

```
// Correct approach for default values
var prev = (a = new Date()) => a;

// Incorrect approach
var prev = a = new Date() => a; // Nope. Where does the arrow function start?
var prev = a = (new Date()) => a; // Invalid parameter name right?
```

Why?

Because in `var prev = a = new Date() => a;` the compiler thinks you are asking:

- Make `prev` equal the value `a` which equals the value of an `arrow function` with `new Date()` as the *parameter name*? Error!

It's not explicit enough so the compiler doesn't like it. If you have defaults wrap them in parentheses.

Read more on [MDN Default Params](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

Answer (score 4):

In first case you are trying to declare 2 variables: `prev` and `a`. And the value you are assigning is incorrect. The result is the same as if you tried to execute `new Date() => a` directly in the console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token new

In second case you are declaring only one variable `prev`. And the value is a function with one argument `a` set by default to `new Date()`.

See also [In JavaScript, is chained assignment okay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387247/in-javascript-is-chained-assignment-okay)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [ecmascript spec for arrow function hasinitializer](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions-static-semantics-hasinitializer), you can see the definition for an arrow function that has an iniitializer:

> ArrowParameters : CoverParenthesizedExpressionAndArrowParameterList

and the definition of `CoverParenthesizedExpressionAndArrowParameterList` is:

> CoverParenthesizedExpressionAndArrowParameterList[Yield] :
>   **(** Expression[In, ?Yield] **)**
>   **( )**
>   **(** ... BindingIdentifier[?Yield] **)**
>   **(** Expression[In, ?Yield] , ... BindingIdentifier[?Yield] **)**

You can see that when you have a default initializer, arrow params must be in `()`, so it is a structure of the language itself