# how to assign same value to two variables in one line

Tags: javascript

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].onclick = function(ev) {
  this.innerHTML, this.parentNode.id = "Z";
 
  //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  //this.innerHTML = "Z";
  //this.parentNode.id = "Z";
}
```

```css
#Z {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>x</span>
</div>
```

i want to apply the value **"Z"** in to **this.innerHTML, this.parentNode.id** in a single line instead of two lines but it doesn't work using comma

Comment: Don't compress your developement code, let a compressing tool do it for the production code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just chain the assignments.

Maybe worth a look: [In JavaScript, is chained assignment okay?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3387247/)

The [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) has a different purpose and result.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].onclick = function(ev) {
    this.innerHTML = this.parentNode.id = "Z";
}
```

```css
#Z { color: red; }
```

```html
<div><span>x</span></div>
```