# In javascript, what do multiple equal signs mean?

Tags: javascript, variables, equals

I saw this code somewhere, but what does it mean? (all a, b, c are defined previously)

```
var a = b = c;
```

Comment: seems neat, does this syntax work in other popular languages? (python, java, c++, pascal, etc)

Comment: yeah, this is the same for almost all languages.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49160043/3786285 this answer is much better

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It quickly assigns multiple variables to a single value.

In your example, `a` and `b` are now equal set to the value of `c`.

It's also often used for a mass assign of `null` to clean up.

```
a = b = c = d = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a shorthand for:

```
var a;
var b;
b=c;
a=b;
```

It's meant as a combination of assigning the same value to two or more other variables, and declaring these variables in local scope at the same time.

You can also use this syntax independently of the var declaration:

```
var a;
var b;
a=b=c;
```

Comment: short hand for
`b=c;`
`var a = b;`

Answer (score 0):

1. Assign c to b.
2. Assign b to a.

So if I say `var a = b = 1;`

```
>>> var a = b = 1;
undefined
>>> a
1
>>> b
1
```

Answer (score 0):

This means `a`, `b` and `c` are the same reference.

For example:

```
var c = {hello: "world"};
var a = b = c;

// now all three variables are the same object
```