# How does a.x = a = {n: b} work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

This is related to [Javascript a=b=c statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511279/javascript-a-b-c-statements?lq=1).

I do understand that

```
foo = foo.x = {n: b}; // console.log(foo) => {n: b}
```

but

```
foo.x = foo = {n: b}; // console.log(foo) => {n: b}
```

It should equal to :

```
foo = {n: b};
foo.x = foo; // console.log(foo) => {n: b, x:object}
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: console.log(foo.x) should print out the same thing.

Comment: I got an error "Cannot set property 'x' of undefined"

Comment: I don't see how the first line could work unless `foo` was *already* referencing some object. (And really the same applies to the second one, though intuitively the second "feels" like it should work as is.)

Comment: You say what it *should* equal, without any justification. There is no justification, because the statement is false. **Can you explain to me why you believed this false thing**?  It helps me to understand why people believe false things about programming languages.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because when you write

```
var foo = {};
foo.x = foo = {n: b} //a=b=c
```

while the line is being executed, foo is pointing to `{}` but when this statement is broken down to

```
foo.x = (foo = {n: b}) /a=(b=c)
```

foo's reference has changed from `{}` to `{n:b}` but `foo` in `foo.x` (a) is still pointing to old reference of `foo` since **left hand expression was evaluated before assignment had begun**.

As per the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation)

> 1. If LeftHandSideExpression is neither an ObjectLiteral nor an
>      ArrayLiteral,
>
>    a. then Let lref be the result of evaluating
>      LeftHandSideExpression.

Which means before the assignment `foo.x` was still having reference to old `foo`.

So, if you tweak your example a little bit by doing

```
var foo = {z:2};
foo.x = foo.n = {n: 1};
```

In this example, you didn't change the reference to `foo`, only assigned new property, so the output now is

> Object {z: 2, n: Object, x: Object}

Now, it has retained the reference to old `foo` since a new reference was not assigned hence all properties `z`, `n` and `x` are being retained.

Answer (score 18):

With:

```
foo.x = foo = {n: b};
```

The leading `foo.x` is partially evaluated first, enough to determine the exact target for the assignment, before proceeding to actually assign it.

It behaves more along the lines of:

```
var oldFoo = foo;
foo = {n: b};
oldFoo.x = foo;
```

---

[This is mentioned in the standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation). The left side of the `=` is evaluated (1.a) before the value is placed there (1.f):

> *AssignmentExpression* : *LeftHandSideExpression* = *AssignmentExpression*
>
> 1) If *LeftHandSideExpression* is neither an *ObjectLiteral* nor an *ArrayLiteral*, then
>   a) **Let *lref* be the result of evaluating *LeftHandSideExpression*.**
>   ...
>   f) Perform ? PutValue(*lref*, *rval*).

Answer (score 6):

It equals

```
let tmp = foo;
foo = {n: b};
tmp.x = foo;
```

You could see, that old `foo` (stored in `z` in this example) was modified:

```
> z=foo={};
{}
> foo.x = foo = {n: b};
{ n: 10 }
> foo
{ n: 10 }
> z
{ x: { n: 10 } }
```

Comment: The other answers describe that this is what's happening, but an example with `tmp` and `foo` initially having the same object as their value makes this much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I got it.

```
var foo = {}; // now foo is a reference point to object {}
foo.x = foo = {n:1}; // first foo is refer to a new object {n:1}, then old foo referred object {} set a prop x

// try this to get what you want
var foo = foo1 = {};
foo.x = foo = {n:1};
console.log(foo, foo1) // here foo1 is what you want
```