# What's the result of this JavaScript code snippet, and why?

Tags: javascript

I'm a newby of JavaScript and just met this question. Can't figure it out by googling and searching on stackoverflow. Code snippet is as following:

```js
var a = { n : 1};    
var b = a;    
a.x = a = {n:  2};    
console.log(a.x);
console.log(b.x);
```

According to my current knowledge, `a.x = a = {n:2};` equals to :

```js
a = {n : 2};
a.x = a;
```

Which eventually make a equals to `{n:2, x:{n:2}}`. So `a.x` should equal to `{n:2}`, and because `b = a`, so `b.x = {n:2}`.
But the result I run in browser is : `alert(a.x)` is `undefined` and `alert(b.x)` is `[object object]`.

Can someone explain why? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

This is a matter of operator precedence, and the matter is that there are *three* operators involved here: `=`, `=`, and `.`.

`.` has higher operator precedence than `=`, which means that `a.x` is evaluated *before* the assignments take place. After that, reassigning `a` mid-statement cannot affect the value of `a` in the expression `a.x` because it has already been evaluated.

We can observe this with the following code:

```js
var _a;
var logging = false;
Object.defineProperty(window, 'a', { 
    get: function () {
        if (logging) {
            console.log('getting a'); 
        }
        return _a; 
    }, 
    set: function (val) { 
        if (logging) {
            console.log('setting a');
        }
        _a = val; 
    }
});

a = { n : 1};    
var b = a;

logging = true;
a.x = a = {n:  2};
logging = false;

console.log(a.x);
console.log(b.x);
```

What we can see here is that `a`'s getter is being accessed *before* its setter in the process of the statement we're talking about, and it's only being accessed once. This tells us that `a.x` is being evaluated *before* `a.x = ....`.

Where you're going wrong is that that statement actually evaluates like this:

```
a = {n:  2}
[the value that a referred to before the statement started executing].x = {n : 2};
```

In other words, the identifier `a` is "bound" before the statement begins executing and property references will refer to that bound value for the duration of the statement.

In this case, `[the value that a referred to before the statement started executing]` is equivalent to `b`, but it's not equivalent to the new value of `a`. That's why `b.x` has a value and `a.x` does not.

You could say that the process works out to be something like this:

```js
var a = { n : 1};    
var b = a;

var temp = a;
var newVal = {n: 2};
a = newVal;
temp.x = newVal;

console.log(a.x);
console.log(b.x);
```

and this produces the same outcome as your original code.

The [ECMAScript Spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1) lays out the procedure for evaluating an *AssignmentExpression* of the form *LeftHandSideExpression* **=** *AssignmentExpression*. The first two steps are:

1. Let lref be the result of evaluating LeftHandSideExpression.
2. Let rref be the result of evaluating AssignmentExpression.

This clearly shows that the *left hand side* of an assignment is evaluated *before* the right hand side is evaluated.

Comment: This does not have anything to do with precedence (or associativity). Rather, it's the order in which operands are evaluated, specifically the operands `a.x` and `a = {n:  2}`. The reason the result is surprising (to me) is that `=` is right-associative, but still evaluates operands left-to-right. Other than that nitpick, your answer is correct and very informative.

Answer (score 0):

a.x in this scenario is undefined because

a reference in a.x has been changed to new reference value due to second assignment ( a = {n:2})

Reading value of property with old reference is undefined , as it got changed

To see difference add new property , something like this

a.x = a.y = {n:2} // this will not change the reference of **a**

```
console.log(a.x);//{n:2}
console.log(a.y);//{n:2}
console.log(b.x);//{n:2}
```

https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/JpeENv

More details from the similar question here - [How does a.x = a = {n: b} work in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008672/how-does-a-x-a-n-b-work-in-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You've run into something called [`operator precedence/associativity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

Consider their example:

```
a = b = 5;
```

> with the expected result that a and b get the value 5. This is because
>   the assignment operator returns the value that is assigned. First, b
>   is set to 5. Then the a is also set to 5, the return value of b = 5,
>   aka right operand of the assignment.

This breaks down to:

```
b = 5
a = the return of b which is now 5.

a.x = a = {n:  2};
```

Breaks down into:

```
a = {n: 2}
a.x = the return of a = {n: 2}
```

Since b is a reference to a, it is altered after the assignment.

Comment: Your doc linked here says: `Assignment operators are right-associative`

Comment: Huh, you appear to be right. Assignment operations have right associativity

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain why `a.x` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
a.x = a = {n:2};
```

is the same as

```
var a = b = 1;
```

both variables a and b will be set to 1;

Now since you are working with an object and assigning a value to itself ( you would actually be creating a loop, but non the less the routine in JS gets confused ( which it should ).

basically the issue is the order of evaluation.

This is just my take on it after experimenting with it. I Would like to hear what other answers the community has though.