# Unfamiliar Javascript Syntax

Tags: javascript, syntax

Long and short of the story is, whilst reading John Resig's blog (specifically http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-trie-performance-analysis/) I came across a line which makes absolutely no sense to me whatsoever. Essentially it boils down to

```
object = object[key] = something;
```

(this can be found in the first code block of the article I've linked.)

This has proven rather difficult to google, so if anyone can offer some insight / a good online resource for me to learn for myself, I'd much appreciate it.

To claify on a single point, the object in the multiple assignment is the same ie.

```
A = A[key] = something;
```

Perhaps my question should be, what's the point in doing this?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/1758912/1225328](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1758912/1225328)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line assigns something to object[key] and object. You can read it like so:

```
object[key] = something;
object = object[key];
```

Comment: marked as answer as 1) was first 2) clear and concise! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is called [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties)

> Properties of JavaScript objects can also be accessed or set using a
>   bracket notation. Objects are sometimes called associative arrays,
>   since each property is associated with a string value that can be used
>   to access it. So, for example, you could access the properties of the
>   myCar object as follows:

```
myCar["make"] = "Ford";
myCar["model"] = "Mustang";
myCar["year"] = 1969;
```

**UPDATE** Ah, I missed the two equals. - multiple assignment as mentioned in another answer

**NOTE:** It is unlikely that you would want

```
object=object[somekey]=something
```

since it would overwrite the object you just used in the middle but rather

```
objectA=objectB[somekey]=something
```

where objectA would  be the same type as objectB[somekey] **and** *something*

Answer (score 0):

It's called multiple assignment.

Let's make an example:

```
a = b = 5;
```

After this instruction the value of **both a and b** is **5**.

It's like doing:

```
a = 5;
b = 5;
```

Comment: You're wrong, `a = b = 5` is like `b = 5; a = 5`, not `a = 5; b = 5`.

Comment: Right, or better... b = 5; a = b;

Comment: I have edited my question ever so slightly, to account that the object for each assignment is the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's a combination of multiple assignment and bracket notation.

You could also read it like this:

```
// Key is a string value!
var key = 'foobar';
object[key] = something;    
object = something;


// Or, if key is known
object.foobar = something;
object = something;
```

Comment: Great you can take two answers and join them into one - well done :|