# Is there a way to assign multiple variables a same value or attribute?

Tags: python, variable-assignment

In Python, is there a way to make

```
a, b, c, d, e = 'dog'
```

so that

```
a = 'dog'

b = 'dog'

#etc.
```

or

```
a, b, c, d, e = list()
```

so that

```
type(a through e)
```

returns

```
type 'list'
```

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: `a = b = c = d = e = 'dog'` in all C successors, including C++, Java, C#, PHP and other.

Comment: @mopo922 Python! sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has already been answered here:
[Set multiple variables to the same value in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975350/set-multiple-variables-to-the-same-value-in-javascript)

in python it would be:

```
a = b = c = d = e = 'dog'
```

its the same in javascript but with 'var' at the beginning:

```
var a = b = c = d = e = 'dog'
```

Answer (score 1):

In c# in would be as simple as declaring the variables and then setting them all equal.

```
string a,b,c,d;

a = b = c = d = "dog";
```