# How to assign the same value to multiple variables

Tags: python, variables

I was wondering if there is a decent way to avoid repeating `"IGNORED"` when assigning it to multiple values in python, something like *"IGNORED" maybe:

```
raw_size, size, content_type, last_modified, error = "IGNORED", "IGNORED", "IGNORED", "IGNORED", {}
```

I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28308920/is-there-a-way-to-assign-multiple-variables-a-same-value-or-attribute) link but it was not quite the answer I was looking for.

Comment: `raw_size = size = content_type = last_modified = error = "IGNORED"` ? or `raw_size, size, content_type, last_modified = ('IGNORED',) * 4` ?

Comment: Because the last variable, i.e. ```error``` should be a different value, i.e. ```{}```

Comment: This doesnt appear good to me but you could do `a, b, c, d = ('IGNORED',) * 3 + ({},)`

Comment: ```a, b, c, d = ('IGNORED',) * 3 + ({},)``` works fine, Thanks.
And I would be thankful if you tell me why that  doesnt appear good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *insist*,

```
raw_size, size, content_type, last_modified, error = ('IGNORED', ) * 4 + ({},)
```

might work.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is:

```py
raw_size = size = content_type = last_modified = "IGNORED"
error = {}
```

If this isn't what you're looking for, please rewrite your question to have more clarity.

Comment: This is working, but I was looking for a way to do it all in one line.

Comment: If I may ask, what's the reason behind that?

Comment: No special reason. I just personally prefer fewer lines. And I'm realizing it is not always a good idea!