# "use strict": Assign Value to Multiple Variables

Tags: javascript, variables, var

Is there any other way in `"use strict";` javascript to initialize a value to multiple variables? Because doing this:

```
var x = y = 14;
```

will cause error: [`Uncaught ReferenceError: y is not defined`](http://jsfiddle.net/tsvzetrw/)

Got my reference here:

[Set multiple variables to the same value in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975350/set-multiple-variables-to-the-same-value-in-javascript)

Comment: Yes, this does successfully *set* multiple variables. But it does only *declare* `x`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are side affects to `var x = y = 14;` which is why it's not allowed in strict mode.  Namely, `y` becomes a global variable.

When you say

```
var x = y = 14;
```

It is equivalent to

```
var x;
y = 14;
x = y;
```

Where `x` is declared as a local variable and `y` is created as a global variable.

For more information on using `var` to declare variables see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-function-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it).  Additionally, it may be worth noting that ES6 is introducing [the keyword `let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) that enables block level scoping in contrast to function level scoping that exists with `var`.

Finally, if you want to assign both variables a value, any of the following would do

```
var x, y;
x = y = 14;

var x = 14,
    y = x;

var x = 14,
    y = 14;

var x = 14;
var y = 14;
```

Comment: The last example still makes `y` global, does it not?

Comment: Actually, `var x = y = 14;` is equivalent to `y = 14; var x = 14;`. But I guess the order is not very important. In that case.

Comment: You are correct.  Thanks @FelixKling.   Edited my answer to reflect your correction.

Comment: I was wrong. You were correct that it is  `var x = 14;` (because `y = 14`) results in `14`.

Comment: @FelixKling If you want to get specific, it's equivalent to `var x; y = 14; x = y;` :D

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: I was considering it, but didn't want to bring in hoisting as well ;)

Comment: Thanks to both @FelixKling and @NiettheDarkAbsol for the corrections.  I've updated my response to what I think we all believe is the correct equivalent to `var x = y = 14;`

Comment: @sfletche—cool, might be handy to include the link: [*What is the function of the var keyword and when to use it (or omit it)?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-function-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it).

Comment: Nice link @RobG.  I included it as well as a link to an explanation for the `let` keyword for additional reading...

Answer (score 7):

Yup - don't mix declarations and assignments.

```
var x, y;
x = y = 14;
```