# How to declare multiple objects at once

Tags: javascript, json, object, javascript-objects, deep-copy

I tried this but it only set the value to `obj1`

```
let obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, ..., objn = {} // only obj1 is set, the rest is undefined.
```

I looked at this post: [assign multiple variables to the same value in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975350/assign-multiple-variables-to-the-same-value-in-javascript) and they suggested this:

```
let obj1 = obj2 = obj3 = obj4 = ... = objn = {}
```

But the above says that any change in `obj1` will affect `obj2`, `obj3`, ...

Is is possible to initialize all `obj` as `{}` at once without a for loop ?

Comment: I think there is no solution without a loop. If you don't want to have kind of a chained reference.

Comment: Why don't you use an array of objects?

Comment: `without a for loop?` yes, you can do it with a `while` loop :D

Answer (score 1):

Using array destructuring assignment, you can use map/reduce to create objects, but neither will be as fast as a for-like loop.

```js
let [o1,o2,o3] = Array(3).fill().map(()=>({}))

o1.id = '1'
o2.id = '2'
o3.id = '3'

console.log(o1)
console.log(o2)
console.log(o3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.assign`, this function come with ES6 syntax, you can check the documentation : [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
const [obj1, obj2, obj3] = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];
Object.assign(this, {obj1, obj2, obj3});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var [obj, obj2, obj3] = [{"a":1},{"a":2},{"a":3}];

console.log(obj);
console.log(obj2);
console.log(obj3);
```

This seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let  {obj1, obj2, obj3 }= {obj1:{}, obj2:{}, obj3:{}};

obj1.id =10;
obj2.id =20;
obj3.id =30;

console.log("obj1",obj1);
console.log("obj2",obj2);
console.log("obj3",obj3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an interesting way to initialize an arbitrary amount of objects without explicitly initializing an array of values. This answer is very similar to [Vol7ron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52453303/1541563) except that this uses a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function*) to lazily iterate values without a pre-allocated array. The iterator returned by `initialize()` will only iterate as far as the [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) requires, so make sure to not use a [`...` rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) in your destructuring assignment or your iterator will never terminate.

```js
function * initialize (fn) { while (true) { yield fn() } }

const [obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5, obj6] = initialize(() => ({}))

// all initialized
console.log(obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5, obj6)
// all unique
console.log(new Set([obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5, obj6]).size)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function declareMultipleObjects(...args){
    var arrayOfObjects = []
    args.forEach(function(each){
        each = new Object();
        arrayOfObjects.push(each);
    })

    alert(arrayOfObjects);}

declareMultipleObjects("obj1", "obj2", "obj3");
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [_How do I write a good answer_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.