# why (var a = b = 1;) is equals to (var a = 1; b = 1;) in javascript?

Tags: javascript

When learning JavaScript I encountered a problem about hoisting that is if you run the code below, what you will get?

```js
f1();
console.log(b);
console.log(a);

function f1() {
  var a = b = 1;
  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
}
```

The answer is you get three 1 ,and an error which makes sense due to hoisting.
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Based on the result, I can infer that `var a = b = 1;` is equals to `var a = 1; b = 1;`

My problem is Why?

I tried to google it but it seems there is no explanation about the order that var and '=' are executed. I would appreciate it that you would show me how the `var a = b = 1;` is executed step by step.

Comment: Read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975350/assign-multiple-variables-to-the-same-value-in-javascript

Comment: `b = 1`, `a = b`, therefore `a` and `b` are both 1? You can see this with `a == 1` (`true`), `b == 1` (`true`), `a == b` (`true`) and `a === b` (`true`)

Comment: @tom10271 Nope, `b` is global.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the confusion is. `b = 1` is first, it sets a global `b`. `a = b` is next, and `a` is scoped to `f1`.

Comment: (Noting the error isn't because of hoisting, rather that there's no `a` in global scope.)

Comment: I got it, so the `b = 1` is first, the expression returns the value 1, and set a new var `a=1` . Problem solved. Thanks you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because [assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment) is an [expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#expressions) which evaluates to the assigned value.  So this operation:

```
b = 1
```

not only assigns the value of `1` to `b` but also the entire expression *evaluates* to the value of `1`.  Since it's an expression which evaluates to a value, it can be used in place any time a value is needed.

This needs a value:

```
var a = (something)
```

So you can use any expression, for example:

```
var a = (b = 1)
```

And the parentheses are unnecessary since the assignment to `a` won't occur until the expression is evaluated and a value produced:

```
var a = b = 1
```

---

What *wouldn't work* is to both *declare and assign* as an expression.  For example:

```
var a = (var b = 1)
```

Because the *declaration* is not an expression, it's a [statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements).  Statements can be thought of as "a line of code" and can't be dropped in-place in the middle of other code.

You can test this in your browser's debugging tools by entering code directly onto the console.  If you do this:

```
var a = 1
```

The console will print `undefined`, because the statement produced no value (even though it did assign a value to `a`).  If you do this:

```
b = 1
```

The console will print `1` because the expression produced a value (as well as assigned a value to `b`).

---

Regarding the rest of the code being tested in the question, the key difference between `a` and `b` is that `a` is *declared* and thus has [a specific scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), whereas `b` is not declared and thus defaults to a property on the `window` object which is accessible anywhere.