# Multiple Addition-Assignment Operators in One Statement

Tags: javascript, syntax

I'm wondering if JavaScript allows multiple addition-assignment operators in one statement. I know about multiple variable assignment, discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758576/multiple-left-hand-assignment-with-javascript).

My current way of coding looks somewhat like this:

```
var x = someComplicatedFunction();
foo += x;
bar += x;
```

Is there a way to do something like this?

```
foo, bar += someComplicatedFunction();
```

Comment: are you trying to set `foo` and `bar` to the same value? Or trying to add the same value to both?

Comment: @LeeMeador I'd like to add the same value to both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put as many statements as you want in one line :

```
var x = someComplicatedFunction(); foo += x; bar += x;
```

If you want to do everything in one statement, it's more messy but it's doable :

```
bar -= foo - (foo += someComplicatedFunction());
```

But there's nothing magical letting you do everything in one statement without assignation *and* being readable.

Comment: The second statement is very clever, albeit at the expense of readability. I was wondering if JavaScript had some syntactic sugar I wasn't aware of.

Comment: Note that the only reason to use the second form would be to avoid cluttering the namespace. It's not faster (it's faster than using an IIFE to avoid the x variable but you rarely need to increment two variables without being in a local scope that you can pollute).