# JavaScript assigning self variable

Tags: javascript

How comes this works:

```
function Test() {
    this.t=function() {
        var self=this;
        self.tutu = 15;
        console.log(self);
    }
}
var olivier = new Test();
```

This works:

```
function Test() {
    this.t=function() {
        var self  = this,
            other = -1;
        self.tutu = 15;
        console.log(self);
    }
}
var olivier = new Test();
```

And this *doesn't* work (with the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`):

```
function Test() {
    this.t=function() {
        var self  = this,
            other = -1,
            self.tutu = 15;
        console.log(self);
    }
}
var olivier = new Test();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var` statement is used to declare variables. So, you are trying to define a variable with name `self.tutu`, which is not valid in JavaScript, as variable names should not have `.` in their names. That is why it is failing with Syntax error.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

Quoting from [Variables section in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Variables),

> A JavaScript identifier must start with a letter, underscore (_), or dollar sign ($); subsequent characters can also be digits (0-9). Because JavaScript is case sensitive, letters include the characters "A" through "Z" (uppercase) and the characters "a" through "z" (lowercase).
>
> Starting with JavaScript 1.5, you can use ISO 8859-1 or Unicode letters such as å and ü in identifiers. You can also use the \uXXXX Unicode escape sequences as characters in identifiers.

Comment: If I try `self['tutu']` it's the same problem.

Comment: @OlivierPons Correct, because `[`, `'` and `]` are also not allowed in variable declarations.

Comment: @OlivierPons In other two examples, you are assigning to a property of an object, but in the last example you are trying to create a variable with invalid characters in the identifier

Comment: Try this: `var a={ t: 15}, b=a.t;` and this: `var a={ t: 15}, b=a['t'];`. It works for me with Chrome

Comment: @OlivierPons In this case, variable names are just `a` and `b`. Values can be anything. For example, try `var a={t: 0}, a.t = 15;`, it will fail. Because it has a problem with the variable name `a.t`

Comment: Aaaaaaaaah I understand what you mean. Thank you very much for this clean explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`var` could only used to declare variables, but not before expression.

`var self.tutu = 15;` is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

The last pattern doesn't work because you are creating a property of `self` within the variable declaration block. You could rewrite your code to:

```
var self = (this.tutu = 15, this),
           other = -1;
/* self = (this.tutu = 15, this) =>
   (,) creates a group. Using the comma operator,
   the statements within the group are evaluated from
   left to right. After evaluation self is a reference to this
   and this now also contains the property tutu */
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty similar to this:
[Multiple left-hand assignment with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758576/multiple-left-hand-assignment-with-javascript)

Per that answer, you're actually doing this: `var self = (window.other = (self.tutu = 15))`, which of course will give the SyntaxError, because you're trying to assign `self.tutu` before `self` exists.

I'm not sure there's a way to do parallel assignment in this way, but of course

```
var self = this;
var other = -1;
self.tutu = 15;
```

will work fine.

Comment: I'm not trying to assign "self.tutu before self exists.". In Javascript, you can do this: `var a={ t: 15}, b=a.t;` and it works flawlessly, which is pretty similar to what I'm asking.