# In JavaScript, create 7 variables with the same value but different names

Tags: javascript, variables

In JavaScript, how do I make a for loop that would make 7 variables with the same value,but different names. So, I want to take a string and subtract the last two letters. I do this with

```
var stringExample = prompt("Blah blah"); 
var stem = stringExample.substring(0, stringExample.length-2);
```

And then make 6 more of the stem variables with the names of stem0 through stem6. Right now my code is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    eval('var stem' + i + '= toDecline.substring(0, toDecline.length - 2');
};
```

Comment: So you want an array...

Comment: Most likely there is a better way to do what ever you are trying to do. Post what you are trying to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use dynamic variable names in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var stem = stringExample.substring(0, stringExample.length-2);
var stem0 = stem1 = stem2 = stem3 = stem4 = stem5 = stem6 = stem;
```

Note some [**implications with regard to scope**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758576/multiple-left-hand-assignment-with-javascript) when doing this. Essentially, the subsequent variables are initialized in the global namespace. Remedy that by defining them in advance.

That said, I suspect that your application logic could be simplified to avoid needing 7 identical variables.

Comment: how about: `var stem0 = stem1 = stem2 = stem3 = stem4 = stem5 = stem6 = stringExample.substring(0, stringExample.length-2);`

Comment: @isherwood I keep trying to figure out how to solve the problem of the 7 variables. Later, I add text to the end of the string with using `var nom = stem0 += 'a';`. But then, when I add another line `var gen = stem0 += 'ae';` it ends up making the vale of `gen` the value of `nom += 'ae'` I need seven variables because I make a var like nom or gen 7 times, and it just keeps tacking more text on the end. Any ideas on that?

Comment: using `var stem0 = stem1 = stem2 = stem3 = stem4 = stem5 = stem6 = stem;` worked.

Comment: @n00bie If you aren't declaring those other variables earlier, then they will be global, which is generally a REALLY bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

you can have it like this:

```
  var stem = stringExample.substring(0, stringExample.length-2);
    var stemr=[];
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    stemr[i]=stem;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use an array.

```
var stemArray = [];
var value = stringExample.substring(0, stringExample.length-2);

for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    stemArray[i] = value;
};
```

Comment: Hmmm....Maybe my code is off, but that did not work. `var toDecline = prompt("Enter the word's genitive");
    var stem = toDecline.substring(0,toDecline.length - 2);
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        all1[0] = stem += 'a';
        all1[1] = stem += 'ae';
        all1[2] = stem += 'ae';
        all1[3] = stem += 'am';
        all1[4] = stem += 'a';
        all1[5] = stem += 'ae';
        all1[6] = stem += 'arum';
        all1[7] = stem += 'is';
        all1[8] = stem += 'as';
        all1[9] = stem += 'is';
    };
    console.log(all1);` P.S. I am making a Latin word decliner.

Comment: What doesn't work? Btw, in your code, that loop does nothing.