# Advice on Javascript variable initialization

Tags: javascript, variable-initialization

Is it ok in Javascript to declare multiple variables as below?

```
var foo = bar = "Some value";
```

Comment: You may get "scoping problems", have a look at [Issues with this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758576/multiple-left-hand-assignment-with-javascript) for detailed explaination

Answer (score 5):

Unless you are aware that you are creating a global variable (which is mostly considered bad practice, anyway), it's not ok.

If you came from a language like Java, it's natural to do something like:

```
int foo = bar = 0;
```

Both variables *foo* and *bar* will be initialized with value 0, both inside the current scope. But in Javascript:

```
var foo = bar = 0;
```

Will create the variable *foo* inside the current scope and a **global** variable *bar*.

#### The problem

I was debugging on a game I'm writing for about an hour, before understanding my mistake. I had a code like:

```
function Player() {
    var posX = posY = 0;
}

function Bullet() {
    var posX = posY = 0;
}

var player = new Player;
var bullet = new Bullet;
```

Variable *posY* is global. Any method on one object that changes the value of *posY* will also change it for the other object.

What happened: every time a *bullet* object moved through the screen vertically (changing what it should be it's own *posY*), the *player* object would be teleported to *bullet*'s Y coordinate.

Solved by simply separating the variable declaration to:

```
var posX = 0;
var posY = 0;
```

Comment: ... or `var posX = 0, posY = posX;`

Comment: @Pointy nice, concise alternative!