# Multiple left-hand assignment with JavaScript, really right associative?

Tags: javascript

In this post, [Multiple left-hand assignment with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758576/multiple-left-hand-assignment-with-javascript), @Crescent Fresh says JavsScript left-hand assignment is right associative. But the following code seems to me it breaks right associativeness:

```
var a = {n: 1};
a.x = a = {n: 2};
console.log(a.x);// undefined
```

Can anyone explain why `a.x` is undefined?

Edit:The snippet above is to test "right associativeness", in real world please do not write similar code.

Comment: Circular reference, `a.x = a`

Comment: @Tushar Nope, try it yourself in chrome console.

Comment: @尤慕李 The first assignment `a.x = a` is removed/overwritten by second `a = {n: 2};`

Comment: Food for thought — http://jsbin.com/fagokazido/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: @Tushar — No, it isn't.

Comment: @EdHeal See my edit:)

Comment: Please write code that is readable. Do not rely on people having the think too much to understand the code. It will bite you. Remember KISS

Comment: @EdHeal — Multiple assignment is a common pattern in JS. This particular example happens to hit a weird edge case.

Comment: Back to the question - Why make life difficult - Simple chaining of assignments OK.. Other than that no (think of the reviewer and the person doing maintenance)

Comment: kudos for asking an interesting question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

tl;dr — JS works out where to put the value before working out what that value is, and a side effect of working out what that value is changes the value of `a`.

---

See the [spec for simple assignment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1).

Step 1 is "Let lref be the result of evaluating LeftHandSideExpression."

Step 2 is "Let rref be the result of evaluating AssignmentExpression."

So the first thing that happens is that a property `x` is created on the object stored in `a` (where n is 1).

Then the right hand side is evaluated (which ends up overwriting `a` with a new object where n is 2).

Then the result of that expression (that object where n is 2) is assigned to `x` on the original object (where n is 1).

You can see this in effect with:

```js
"use strict";
var a = {n: 1};
var b = a;

a.x = a = {n: 2};

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Comment: Answers from @JLRishe and Quentin are both correct, but stackoverflow allows only one answer to be accepted:(. I have voted up both and accepted the latter because an answer with specifaction referencing is more solid and convincing. Thank you, sir.

Comment: For js **reference**, here is a great article [Why is (0,obj.prop)() not a method call](http://www.2ality.com/2015/12/references.html) from Dr. Axel Rauschmayer

Answer (score 7):

It is right associative. It's simply that the identifier `a` is bound to a reference before the statement executes.

We can witness this with the following:

```
var a, b;
a = b = { n: 1 };
a.x = a = {n: 2};  // a.x refers to the x property of the value a references
                   //     before this statement executes
console.log(a);    // {n: 2}
console.log(b);    // {n: 1, x: {n: 2}}
```

If `=` were left associative, `b.x` would be a circular reference back to `b` after the third line executes, but it isn't.

---

> Can anyone explain why a.x is undefined?

Yes, this is what happens when the line `a.x = a = {n: 2}` executes:

1. The value `{n: 2}` is assigned to the variable `a`
2. The value `{n: 2}` is assigned to the `x` property of the object that `a` referred to *before the statement started executing*.

Nothing is assigned to the `x` property of `a`'s new value. That's why `a.x` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

in java script Objects are passed around by reference. They are never copied.

```
var a = {n:1}
```

so earlier a has reference of an object which has a property n=1

on second statement
    `a.x = a = {n:2}` 
a.x has added a property x on previous object whose value is an object with property n = 2 
the same statement assign a the reference of new object.

Comment: javascript note no space between java and script