# Javascript: variable = variable2 = variable3

Tags: javascript, variables, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

I don't know how to describe this, but this doesn't error out in Javascript... but it doesn't mean its a good idea and that all versions of Javascript except it (or not).

Thoughts?

```
var r = 'r';
var t = 't';
var s = 's';

s = r = t;

// s = 't'
// r = 't'
// t = 't'
```

It doesn't seem standard and it may be harder for a developer to follow, but are there really any use cases for this?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758576/multiple-left-hand-assignment-with-javascript

Comment: It doesn't seem standard and it may be harder for a developer to follow, but are there really any use cases for this?

Comment: Nothing non-standard whatsoever, See example in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators

Comment: "standard"? What does the "standard" term mean?

Comment: Are you need suggestion ?

Comment: This is standard practice... Even C accepts this... Equivalent to `s = (r = t)`

Comment: This is part of the spec (so it is "standard"?): http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-assignment-operators . If you come across an environment where this doesn't work, it's a bug. I wonder if you are basically asking why an assignment is an expression and not a statement (in which case `x = y = z` would be a syntax error)?

Answer (score 1):

This works because the assignment of r=t returns the assigned value. So yes you can infinitely assign values based on return values.

Answer (score 1):

It is a fairly standard practice to chain assignments together. It even has a name called ["chain assignment"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)#Chained_assignment). I don't know where you get the idea of "this is bad coding" from, but this is definitely a normal thing to see. This works because assignments return the assigned value.

This is commonly used for initializing variables:

```
var a, b, c;
a = b = c = 5;  //one use case
//same as
a = (b = (c = 5)));
```

> It doesn't seem standard and it may be harder for a developer to follow.

If a developer cannot understand this expression, I don't know what to say.

Answer (score 0):

I use it all the time in my modules to create a local shortcut to functions (for use within the module):

```
var doSomething = module.exports.doSomething = ()=>{};
```

It's nice the way javascript returns values. In languages like python you have to do this sort of thing way to often:

```
def do_something(ctx):
    ctx.update({
        'entry': entry,
        'section': 'select_category'
    })
    do_something_else(ctx)
```

instead of

```
def do_something(ctx):
    do_something_else(ctx.update({
        'entry': entry,
        'section': 'select_category'
    })
```

because the update method doesn't return anything.