# Assign two variables to the same value with one expression?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there any way to assign two variables to the same value?

Just tried this:

```
let x, y = 'hi'
```

and it's compiling to this:

```
'use strict';

var x = void 0,
    y = 'hi';
```

Comment: `let x = 'hi', y = x;`  - that's the only way to do that in a single statement.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1758912/5812121

Comment: What are you trying to do anyway?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
let x, y;
x = y = 'hi';
```

It is called chaining assignment, making possible to assign a single value to multiple variables.
See more details about [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Assignment).

---

If you have more than 2 variables, it's possible to use the array destructing assignment:

```
let [w, x, y, z] = Array(4).fill('hi');
```

Answer (score 7):

There is absolutely no reason to prefer the destructuring assignment over simply

```
let x = 'hi', y = x;
```

Not only it's one statement instead of two, but it also avoids extra allocations (the provided solution with destructuring allocates at least one object with no good reason).

Comment: Ok, but what about 5 variables? `let x = 'hi', a = x, b = x, c = x, d = x`. Too hard to read.

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin just don't write code that requires you to create 5 identical variables (it looks awkward in the very first place)

Comment: @zerkms I think you meant to say "There is absolutely no reason to prefer _the destructuring assignment_ to `let x = 'hi', y = x;`"

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen yep thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way .. But my suggest try to avoid it.

```
var one, two, three;
one = two = three = "";
```

Comment: JS by itself doesn't use explicitly defined types such as string.

Comment: Why should I avoid it?

Comment: @torazaburo because it's a strong positive sign that you're doing something wrong. Just create one variable, not 3 with the same data.

Comment: Huh? What if I have two or three distinct variables, that I happen to want to initialize to the same value?

Comment: @torazaburo I don't remember last time I did that. Any chance you can make of an algorithm/a task where it's the mandatory implementation detail?

Comment: I don't really care, and it's a semi-stupid question, but yes, I can easily imagine cases where I have two counters, let's say, and want to initialize them both to zero. However, I see no reason not to just say `var x=0, y=0;`.

Answer (score 0):

That's expected behavior. From the [EMCA-262 6th edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations):

> If a *LexicalBinding* in a `let` declaration does not have an
>   `Initializer` the variable is assigned the value `undefined` when the
>   *LexicalBinding* is evaluated.

Answer (score -2):

```
var x = y = 'hi';
alert('x'+x);
alert('y'+y);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)