# what does require('jquery') return and why multiple assignments

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am new to nodejs and javascript and I tried to get an answer for this question but after investing plenty of time, I couldn't find an answer on the internet.
I now know what `require` and `export` are doing. I am analyzing some code and it has the following code line:

```
var $ = global.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery');
```

So here as I have understood the export object of `'jquery'` is returned. As I have read from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758576/multiple-left-hand-assignment-with-javascript), the code is equal to:

```
var $ = (global.jQuery = (window.$ = require('jquery')));
```

I hope that this is correct. If not, what is the code meaning? Then my question is, what is now `var $` containing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what does `require('jquery')` return

`require('jquery')` returns a new `jquery` object, exported by `modules.export` as you're already familiar with.  As any Node module, you can assign this to whatever you like.

Don't be confused by the `$`, it's a valid variable name in JavaScript.

> why multiple assignments

Syntactical, one-liner convenience, that's all.

- `window.$` is for compatibility with running in the browser
- `global.jQuery` is two fold.

  - Having `jQuery` available is a great fallback for when `$` is unavailable such as when running multiple versions of jQuery.  I've found this to be fairly common in large projects due to compatibility differences with some 3rd party projects.
  - Since variables are usually `locally` scoped in Node by default, `global` has [additional, reserved meaning](https://www.w3resource.com/node.js/nodejs-global-object.php) to make the `jQuery` object available to other portions of code without `require()`ing it again.
- `$` is the [most common usage in the API examples](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html), so it's there for comfort, not necessity.

Comment: Thanks. Very complete answer

Answer (score 2):

In javascript you can make multiple value assignments in the same statement.

Multiple `=` get evaluated right to left. Thus in your example `$` is `jQuery` which is what is imported from the `require`

Simple visual example:

```js
var obj_1={};
var obj_2={};

// creates properties on both objects and assigns same value to all 3 variables
var someVar = obj_1.a = obj_2.b = 10; 

console.log('obj_1', obj_1)
console.log('obj_2', obj_2)
console.log('someVar', someVar)
```

Answer (score 1):

All three of `$`, `global.jQuery` and `window.$` are set to the return value of `require('jquery')`.  I'm not entirely sure what the reason is.

I have used this pattern when working with objects to set a property of an object and a short working variable at the same time, eg:

```
this.myMethod = function (value) {
  var n = this.someReallyLongPropertyName = value;
  // no way am I typing this.someReallyLongPropertyName again!
  if (n == 1) return n % n * n + n;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`var $ = global.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery');`

is equivalent to

```
window.$ = require('jquery');
global.jQuery = window.$;
var $ = global.jQuery;
```

This according to me is just syntactic sugar to let people people who consume jQuery, do so however they want ($, or jQuery or jQ etc.)