# What is the variable equals variable equals function paradigm called in JavaScript? Vue example

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs

This may be too basic but it's escaping me at the moment. I have accidentally created the following working code in Jest whilst writing a test for a Vue application:

```
const updateMethod = wrapper.vm.updateMethod = jest.fn()
expect(updateVal).toHaveBeenCalledWith('methodArgument')
```

I was just wondering what is the name of this sort of an assignment? I'm lacking the thought process at the moment due to burn out to refactor this.

Thank you!

Comment: It's a form of 'chaining' in my book, though not the most common method of doing that in JS

Comment: I've never seen a term for repeated application of the assignment operator. It's important to really understand what it means in the context of a variable declaration as in your example, and it's a good idea to avoid the pattern until you understand it.

Comment: I agree with avoiding it. Some modern languages, like Swift, prevent doing that entirely.

Comment: There's no specific term, it's just a statement that works because it's valid. `wrapper.vm.updateMethod = jest.fn()` is a separate expression that's evaluated first because of operator precedence so this no different than `const updateMethod = whatever`. FWIW, it's a bad practice to assign jest.fn() to mock a function because it cannot be restored. A proper way that doesn't involve multiple assignment is `const updateMethod = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'updateMethod').mockImplementation()`.

Comment: Related question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758576/multiple-left-hand-assignment-with-javascript

Comment: Thank you @EstusFlask, I appreciate the explanation and the spyOn alternative!

Answer (score 1):

This expression assigns the last value to multiple variables. Example:

```js
const a = b = c = d;
```

This means:

```js
c = d;
b = c;
const a = b;
```

As a result, `a`, `b`, `c` end up having the value of `d`.

Comment: `const a = (b = (c = d))` makes it easier to designate existing operator precedence.

Comment: True, however I wouldn skip that pattern entirely. It's not readable.