# What does using multiple = operators do in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, syntax

For example:

What does

```
this.head = this.tail = new Node(value)
```

do? How does javascript interpret this line?

Is this the same as writing:

```
this.head = new Node(value);
this.tail = new Node(value);
```

If so, is there any limitation on when and where this one line approach can be used?

Comment: `a = b = c` is equal to `a = (b = c)`, see [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple left-hand assignment with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758576/multiple-left-hand-assignment-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's assigning the same value to both variables. So it's equivalent to

```
this.tail = new Node(value);
this.head = this.tail;
```

Your equivalence would create 2 different `Node` objects, but there's only 1.