# Why doesn't TypeScript imply array type when assigning to a new empty array?

Tags: typescript, types, casting, variable-assignment, implicit-typing

I usually have the following code:

```
class Foo {
    foo: SomeType[];

    doSomething() {
        const a = this.foo = [];
    }
}
```

In this case, `a` would be `any[]` or `never[]` (depends on environment) instead of `SomeType[]`. If I specify `noImplicitAny` on those that imply `any[]`, the compiler would throw an error.

I know the below cast fixes the problem, but why can't TypeScript deduce the type from `this.foo`?

```
        const a: SomeType[] = this.foo = []; // Have to repeat the type again
```

---

Reproducible code:

`tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true
    }
}
```

`test.ts`:

```
class Foo {

    foo: number[];

    doSomething() {
        const a = this.foo = [];
    }

}
```

TypeScript complaint (at least in VS Code):
[image]

Comment: [I can't reproduce](https://tsplay.dev/Na0zEw) any such implicit any error; can you make sure you've got a [mre] that demonstrates what you're talking about?

Comment: @jcalz Hi, the code in my original question should work, but I added more details. Probably the problem is in VS Code only (I do know VS has this problem as well). In your playground, you don't have an error, but `a` is still `never[]`, which is the main problem.

Comment: Can confirm from ts playgroud, ```a``` is type ```never[]```...interesting [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2EAqBPABxQG8BfAbgFgAoGhAGzgGcnkAxddZYm5P5GJwBcaLLkIQA2gF0qtav2QJ0IJmCgBXBGHRQAFAEpuvRcjAALYEwB0grgF5kMuYtIm+75ABN0GbBdAAc0NjBVM+ZVUwZDhkRwCbOzinWU83alIgA)

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using?  If the issue does turn out to be specific to a particular IDE (this is highly unlikely) then you should probably tag it for that IDE. I understand that `never[]` is also not desired, but until I can get reproducible behavior that both you and I agree is happening then I'm not inclined to spend a lot of effort on researching it.   If you want to change the question to be about `never[]` that's fine; otherwise you should provide enough info for someone to reproduce it (the playground is also using `--noImplicitAny` so that's not the issue)

Comment: Okay, I clarified the question. The problem is not about `noImplicitAny`, it's about not getting the desired array type. Neither `never[]` nor `any[]` is good.

Comment: I think I need to go to sleep soon, but I don't know if I can find a lot of canonical discussion around why assignment expressions behave as they do in TypeScript; I see [ms/TS#37883](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37883) but that's not the same issue.  The actual behavior seems to be that the expression `(x = y)` evaluates to be the inferred type of `y` regardless of the type of  `x`, which isn't wrong *per se* but is not currently your intent.  So I'm  not sure if someone will have an authoritative answer for "why can't TypeScript deduce the type from `this.foo`".

Comment: Interesting this only happens with arrays. If foo is any primitive type or an object, the type is inferred correctly. Correction: The type inferred by typescript for the expression `a = (x = [])` is always `never[]`, but if we just do `let x = []` or `const x = []`, the type is inferred as `any[]`

Comment: I found this interesting answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758576/multiple-left-hand-assignment-with-javascript#answer-1758912). This is a ```javascript``` related solution, but it highlights how assignments are right associated, which would explain the ```never[]``` type. Also assigning a type never to some other type is ok.

Comment: @ash.io I was also looking at the same question lol

Comment: It would make sense if typescript is doing some runtime type checking, but even if `this.foo` is defined (in a constructor for example), the result is still the same, and we still end up with `never[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type being inferred as `any[]` makes sense because Javascript is right-associative wrt the `assignment` operator.

See this question: [Multiple left-hand assignment with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758576/multiple-left-hand-assignment-with-javascript)

This means that the expression:

```
const a = this.foo = [];
```

Is interpreted as:

```
this.foo = [];
const a = [];
```

As you can see, the type information isn't associated with empty array, so `any[]` is the most correct type.

---

You can prove this is in fact what is happening with a simple example:

```
let t: number;
const a = t = 5;
```

The inferred type for `a` would be the literal number `5`, not `number` (which is the type for `t`).

---

It seems that the typescript playground may be wrong in this case, which is why many (including myself) are reporting `never[]` as the inferred type.

Comment: Thanks, I lean towards this explanation too. I am going to send an issue to TypeScript repo. Hopefully they allow this case to make our lives easier. Just that I work on code like this a lot and it's inconvenient to declare the types again.

Comment: Also the playground works correctly. If you turn off `strictNullChecks`, it would act like VS Code, i.e. compile error due to `a` being implicit `any[]`.

Comment: @LukeVo good to know